# How to keep selecting text after right click on somewhere else in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, extjs

I am working for a Web application in IE environment but IE will be expired on June 2022. Therefore, I need to change the environment to Chrome. But some of the behavior between IE and Chrome are different. Such as my problem,

I would like to know how to keep highlighting text if I right click somewhere else? Not right click on the selected text.

For detail:
If there is only one line and one word which is no problem.
If there are three words on one line, highlighted text on the middle and right click on the bottom right area. Highlighted text is gone.

I was trying to add mousedown event before contextmenu event but seemed stupid... and I couldn't find the way to hightlight the document.getSelection text.

Comment: I think the mousedown event approach is not stupid at all.

Comment: hi, i would suggest that you may want to create a fiddle in order to help you further.